# SQL Server not 'CATCH'ing my exception

Tags: sql-server, transactions, try-catch

I have a simple TRY CATCH with an embedded TRANSACTION in the below query.
I have a column name mistyped in the query: `ItemID1` in the second `UPDATE` inside the `TRANSACTION`
When I run the query, I get the below error message which has a severity higher than 10:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line xxx Invalid column name 'ItemID1'.

The 1st `UPDATE` ran successfully (where I was hoping it would `ROLLBACK`).
This shows that it never went to the `CATCH` block.
As per my understanding, the `CATCH` catches errors above severity 10. This one is severity 16, hence it should have caught it.
Any ideas why `CATCH` was never executed?

```
BEGIN TRY
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyTempTable') IS NOT NULL 
        DROP TABLE #MyTempTable
    CREATE TABLE #MyTempTable
        (
          ObjectID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER , OrgID NVARCHAR(20)
        )

    INSERT  INTO #MyTempTable
            SELECT  ObjectTable1.ObjectID AS ObjectID ,OrgID 
            FROM    ObjectTable1 WITH ( NOLOCK ) INNER JOIN Org WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON ObjectTable1.OrgID = Org.OrgID
            WHERE   OrgID IN ('Blah1', 'Blah2')

    INSERT  INTO #MyTempTable
            SELECT  ObjectTable2.ObjectID AS ObjectID, OrgID
            FROM    ObjectTable2 WITH ( NOLOCK ) INNER JOIN Org WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON ObjectTable2.OrgID = Org.OrgID
            WHERE   OrgID IN ('Blah3', 'Blah4')

    SELECT  * FROM #MyTempTable

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        UPDATE  ObjectTable1 
        SET ItemID = NULL FROM ObjectTable1 INNER JOIN #MyTempTable ON #MyTempTable.ObjectID = ObjectTable1.ObjectID
        PRINT 'Updated ' + CAST(@@ROWCOUNT AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' Objects in ObjectTable1'

        UPDATE  ObjectTable2
        SET     ItemID = (ItemID1 + 1) FROM ObjectTable2 INNER JOIN #MyTempTable ON #MyTempTable.ObjectID = ObjectTable2.ObjectID
        PRINT 'Updated ' + CAST(@@ROWCOUNT AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' Objects in ObjectTable2'
    COMMIT
    DROP TABLE #MyTempTable
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
        ROLLBACK
    DROP TABLE #MyTempTable

    DECLARE @ErrMsg NVARCHAR(4000) ,
        @ErrSeverity INT
    SELECT  @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE() ,
            @ErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()
    RAISERROR(@ErrMsg, @ErrSeverity, 1)
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object name resolution errors aren't caught by TRY-CATCH.
From MSDN article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx):

> The following types of errors are not handled by a CATCH block when they occur at the same level of execution as the TRY…CATCH construct:
>
> - Compile errors, such as syntax errors, that prevent a batch from running.
> - Errors that occur during statement-level recompilation, such as object name resolution errors that occur after compilation because of deferred name resolution.